# multi language - each in its own folder?

Tags: language

Craft looks VERY promising to me! Still try to figure out if it could be perfect for our new project, though.

Our website will be in English and German (accessible under ONE domain - see below). I understand that there is a plugin with which I can switch the language while staying on the very same page - PERFEKT!

Here's my questions. Can those requirements be fulfilled by Craft?

- We want the English content to be placed in the folder "website.com/en" and the German in "website.com/de". We would manually put an index.php with a redirect to our default language (not decided yet) in the root folder.
- Can we completely build up the site in one language first - and then kinda "import/duplicate" it to the second language and translate it? language-switch links should still work afterwards. Means: Craft should know which articles of each language belong together.
- There is no 'tab' above an WYSIWYG field under the very same article where I can switch between languages and fill in the corresponding content on the very same admin-page, right?

I'll open another question for my questions concerning my other topics...

Thanks for your help and greetings!

Answer (score 1):

> "there is no 'tab' above an wysiwyg field under the very same article where i can switch between languages and fill in the corresponding content on the very same admin-page, right?"

Actually, there is (sort of). It's not a tab per se, but you can switch between the different versions of *each entry* as you are editing them.

[image: languages]

So you would add all of your entries in English first, then circle back and adjust the content for each entry in German.

And as you mentioned, there is a [Site Switcher](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-siteswitcher) plugin (disclaimer, I am the author) to let you easily switch between languages while staying on the same page.

Comment: hi there.excelent - much better solution than having to duplicate the whole language and then switch back-and-forth between languages  in the backend all the time!

Comment: how about the URLs? will the the above mentioned 'kinda tab' solution automatically create the folders /en and /de?

Comment: If you are using Craft 3, you won't need to create duplicate folders. Everything runs perfectly out of the main folder (even with the `/de` site paths).

Comment: sure, but i do NOT want the default language of the site to be displayed WITHOUT the "/language" folder and the german one WITH "/de" (or vice versa). i do want TWO folders - one specific for each language: "/en" AND "/de"...?

Comment: My point being, you don't need separate folders to pull this off. Whatever your paths are can be handled from a single folder.

Comment: ok, i understand. but my point is that the URLs just DO NEED to be generated/accessible including the language folders "/de" and "/en". that is required by our customer...

Comment: Sure, I believe what you're describing is possible. You may want to spin up a test installation, as there may be some nuances that will shape your decisions.

Comment: can you show me a link to a bilingual craft-site which uses this technique? maybe we can talk about this to our customer..? ;-)

Comment: I'd recommend joining the [Craft Slack](https://craftcms.com/slack) channel. It's a much better place to have an in-depth conversation about a complex topic like localization. :)

Comment: ok, sorry. thought this would be the best place to ask...

Comment: see you there. ;-)